# How to run thin server on autostart Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, thin

I can run the server using this command

```
bundle exec thin start --all /etc/thin
```

rvm is installed under user

How can I run it in Ubuntu on autostart?

I created config file using `thin config -c ...`

**Updated:**

ok, the problem is, I have ruby and all gems installed with RVM under user.

I want to launch standalone server (passenger, thin, doesn't matter).
I can do it under user, but I want to have autostart, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create bash script and then add it to autostart.

Note that you have to use full path to bundle instead of using `bundle` command.

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/your/bundle exec /path/to/your/thin start --all /etc/thin
```

---

*You can find where your **bundle** installed using `which bundle` command.*

---

*Do not forget to make your script executable: `chmod +x /path/to/script.sh`*

Comment: my problem is, that bundle is installed under /home/<user>/.rvm (where my ruby website is) and I want to start it automatically